# Creating domain user login from another domain?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, active-directory

I have two domains named "Domain1" and "Domain2". I have SQL server 2005 in Domain2, and users in Domain1.

How can I create a login in SQL Server 2005 (in Domain2) for the user that is present in Domain1?

Answer (score 3):

In order for one domain to have access to objects in another domain, a [domain trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730798.aspx) needs to be established to allow it. (I'm assuming you don't have a parent-child domain relationship right now.)

This is a configuration change in Active Directory; SQL Server is not involved.

Once a trust is established, the server will be able to see the necessary domain objects when you create the login.